# Rendering problems in Edit Mode in Android Module - Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, rendering

I have a project with 4 Android Modules like this:
[image]

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0. When I'm in edit mode on any layout which is part of an Android Module a rendering problem appears.

**The rendering problem appears when I want to add any custom view in layout for ex. "Toolbar" (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)**

When I deploy the app it works, also I can use for ex. Toolbar in ActivityClass.  I tried to change version from 22.0 to 21.0.1, also I tried to change the app theme in design view but it also didn't work.

I also tried to update Android Studio but it didn't work.

When I open any layout in **"app"** it's rendering good.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Try deleting **C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudioPreview1.2\system\caches** or **C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\.AndroidStudio\system\caches** depending on the version of Android Studio being used, and see if that helps

Comment: @Kai It's not working by deleting system caches. The rendering problem is appearing only when i want to use for ex. CardView or another library! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no problem with Toolbar, but do experience problem with CardView, and it seem to go away when I set the API version to render the layout to 21 (both 22 & 20 don't work for me). So try changing rendering API version and see where that takes you...

Comment: @Kai I tried it but still it's not working. Remember I'm working inside an Android Module. Thanks again :)